# Distinct on one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have look through the duplicated question but the solution there does not work for me.

I have two columns:

```
InstanceID 
ProductID
```

and want to get the unique ProductIDs only.

From others questions asked here I try this solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM  
   (SELECT CAST(A.Col001 AS int) AS SurveyInstanceID , 
           CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(25)) AS ProductID , 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.Col002 ORDER BY A.Col001  DESC) rn
    FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A 
    WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 5 
   ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

but I get as a result duplicated values.

EDIT:

For more information, this is what I have in my table:

```
InstanceID  ProductID


1           10

1           11

1           12

1           13

2           10

2           A1

3           10

3           11  

3           B1  

3           C1  

3           D1

3           E1
......
```

I need to get the unique Product IDs. I am sorry I did not provided example at the beg.

Comment: Please show us the desired output for the data you provided

Comment: What do you want in the result-set? One result per Product? One result per Instance? One result per combination of Instance and Product?

Comment: And what are the datatypes of `Col001` and `Col002`? Why are you converting them?

Comment: Col001 is BIGINT, and Col002 is nvarchar(25), but this all things are happeding in a view, so I can cast them latter if this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

That seems way to complex.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductId from DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant 
WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 5
```

or if you want both columns you will need to specify which InstanceId you will select if there is more than one:

```
SELECT ProductId, MAX(InstanceId)
FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant 
WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 5 
Group BY ProductId
```

If this is not what you are looking for please post your sample data and desired output.

Comment: The first one works off course, but I need and some instance ids to implement security. That's why I need the distinct product ids and one instance id for each.

Comment: Did you try the second method?

Comment: Not working again. I think I did not provided enough information for my columns. I have over one million InstanceID and for each InstanceID I have from 4 to 20 productsID. Maybe you think that for each instance I have the same products, but this is not my case. Sorry about this.

Comment: Can you provide a small set of example data and the desired output?  Based on what I have read, I don't see why the second example would not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates you can use `distint`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(A.Col001 AS int) AS SurveyInstanceID , 
       CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(25)) AS ProductID , 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.Col002 ORDER BY A.Col001  DESC) rn
FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A 
WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 5
```

Comment: What do you want then? Only one per ProductID?